# Dynamic Paths in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, path, helper

I'm trying to create a helper method for my admin links. In quite a few
views I have the code

```
<% if current_user %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_model_path(model) %>
<%= link_to "New", new_model_path %>
<%= link_to "Delete", model, :confirm => "You're a Noob",  :method
=> :delete %>
<% end %>
```

that only display these when logged in.

I would like to do something like this in their place

```
<%= admin_links(model) %>
```

and pass the current item into the application helper method

```
def admin_links(m)
 if current_user
  a = "#{link_to "edit" edit_m_path(m)}"
  a << "#{link_to "new" new_m_path}"
  a << "#{link_to "Delete", m, :confirm => "Your a Noob",  :method
=> :delete}"
 end
end
```

Or something of the like.

Answer (score 57):

basically you need to transform the class name of the model into something pointing to the correct path.

```
model_name = m.class.to_s.underscore
```

And then use it to call the appropriate path methods

```
link_to "edit", send("edit_#{model_name}_path", m)
```

As an aside, you don't need to put the link_tos in `#{}` because that function simply returns a string.

Comment: Please see @v4r's answer, that's the best one available now.

Answer (score 57):

Rails provides polymorphic routes to handle this problem: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

```
= link_to "Edit", polymorphic_path(model), :method => :put
```

Comment: Great answer!
BTW. There are also more specific prefixed polymorphic helpers. So this one can be shorten to `edit_polymorphic_path(model)`

Comment: Another example to "why I love Rails" !!  Is there anything they DIDN'T think of ?!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a partial for this - instead of a helper. Wherever you want to display these links in your views, simply render the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "admin_links", :locals => { :model => model } %>
```

In `_admin_links.html.erb` just paste the original code:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_model_path(model) %>
  <%= link_to "New", new_model_path %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", model, :confirm => "Your a Noob", :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1, Daniel Pietzsch!

Bob, if you're going to use the same code in several views, package it as a partial view and render it wherever you like

Comment: Shouldn't it be `You're a Noob`?!

Comment: I’m just copy-pastin’ ;-)