# Build custom path in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, erb

Is it possible to "build" a path in an erb file like this? The path's name should be dependent on the object's class name. The path being build already exists in the routes.rb file. I just want to dynamically choose a part of the path being generated so I don't have to use a conditional and repetitive code.

```
  <% custom_path = "hide_#{object.class}_path" %>
  <%= link_to 'Do something', custom_path(object) %>
```

The above example doesn't work because I don't know how to "use" the new path correctly. I guess I have to "call" the route by some "meta" way? Like `object.call(method)` in Ruby. But I don't know how to do this in Rails.

An example to clarify: let's say the object's class is Car, then the path in the variable should be: `hide_car_path`.

The error for the example above looks like this:

```
undefined method `custom_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000108afac40>:0x000001091fd3a8>
```

Comment: You can define a helper method `def custom_path(object) "hide_#{object.class}_path end"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038770/dynamic-paths-in-helper

Answer (score 3):

We use [`eval()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#eval-method) for this:

```
<%= link_to 'Do something', eval("custom_#{object.class}_path(object)") %>
```

I'm not sure what it does (not many people like `eval`), and I'm not sure whether the passed variable will persist in my example above, **but** we do use the above code in our own applications

Answer (score 1):

```
<% custom_path = "hide_#{object.class}_path" %>
<%= link_to 'Do something', custom_path(object) %>
```

When you do this, you're making a variable called custom_path and setting it equal to a string.  You then call the string as if it was a method.  It's like doing this:

```
foo = "Bar"
foo("baz")
```

which is like

```
"Bar"("baz")
```

The second argument to link_to is just a string: the path we want to call, like "hide_cars".  The path helpers are just there to help you define that string.  Note that the actual url itself DOES NOT have the word "path" in it:

You can do this:

```
my_path = custom_path(object)
```

then do

```
link_to "Do Something", my_path
```

In your case, however, you want to change the path that's called dynamically, which is a complicated way of getting the resulting string.  It might be simpler for you to do this instead:

```
link_to "Do Something", "/hide_#{object.class.name.undescore.pluralize}"
```

This assumes that the url you want to get is "hide_cars".

Answer (score 1):

Use eval() to do this. eval is used to execute the things which was qiven as string.

for example eval(2+2) # 4

likewise

```
 <%= link_to 'Do something', eval("hide_#{object.class}_path(object)") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. They didn't (only in my case?) work but pushed me into the right direction. The solution was a bit "different" than in the answers though, as I couldn't just use the class name.

The working solution is:

```
  <% path = "approve_#{object.class.to_s.downcase}_path(object)" %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Do something', eval(path) %></td>
```

If I do the following, like in the answers I became:

```
  <% path = "approve_#{object.class}_path(object)" %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Do something', eval(path) %></td>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `hide_Car_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000108afac40>:0x00000101bea990>
```

I figure the object's class in the path has to be lower case. Thanks everyone!